Syntax aware tabulation in Vim
Suppose, we have the following Perl code:
sub test {

    my $a = 1;
    if ($a == 0) {
[cursor]
    }

In Emacs when we click <tab>, it inserts 2 indentations, indenting it according to the if located in the previous line.
And we get this position:
sub test {

    my $a = 1;
    if ($a == 0) {
        [cursor]
    }

When editing the same code in vim I have to press <tab> twice to achieve the same effect:
sub test {

    my $a = 1;
    if ($a == 0) {
[cursor]
    }

<tab>

sub test {

    my $a = 1;
    if ($a == 0) {
    [cursor]
    }

<tab>

sub test {

    my $a = 1;
    if ($a == 0) {
        [cursor]
    }

Is it possible to enable the context aware indentaion in Vim?

I'm convinced Vim is a pretty bad Emacs (and vice versa). Instead of wondering about the differences, familiarize yourself with how Vim works. You can start by reading :help indent.txt

In insert mode you can use Ctrl F to move the cursor to the correct indentation level.
In insert mode Ctrl F reindent the current line provided that the indentkeys option contains !^F (which is the default). When the line is empty it moves the cursor to the correct indentation level.
If you would like to use the Tab for the same you could adapt the indentkeys option:
set indentkeys+=!^I

More information with :help indentkeys-format
Remark: If you would like this to apply only to perl filetype you could have a ~/vimfiles/after/ftplugin/perl.vim with the following content:
setlocal indentkeys+=!^I


Notably this is only for insert mode and the specific key can be customized (cinkeys, maybe? I don’t remember the exact option)

For Perl, that would probably be 'indentkeys' (and 'cinkeys' does the same for C-indentation). I tried with :setlocal indentkeys+=0<Tab> but couldn't get it to work. From my understanding, that would be the answer OP was looking for.

Ah, I didn't realize you have to type ^I as two characters: caret and capital I.
